# PHP Email Bcc from form

Tags: php, forms, email, bcc

I've created a form to get information from end users and email to a specific person. I'd like for the form to also be emailed to the submitter. Everything works, except when I try to Bcc the submitter. If I add the line to Bcc, the email is not sent. If I delete the line to Bcc the email is sent correctly, but the submitter doesn't have a copy of the email. Here is the code,

```
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'From: $email' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Bcc: $email_bcc' . "\r\n";
```

Comment: Why not just send a separate email to the sender? If BCC were a header, it wouldn't be very B, would it?

Answer (score 1):

Add the BCC Receiver to the recipients but NOT to the headers!

Answer (score 1):

Using Bcc in the header should be fine. However, make sure, that your mail server is not killing the mail because of it.[1](http://php.net/manual/de/function.mail.php#89043)

Check the return value of the mail function. This should return false, if an error occured. If that is the case, you should send an extra mail to the sender.

Windows Server seem to have a problem with this.